# (Android) Firebase cloud messaging - ontokenrefresh never called on specific device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was testing fcm on two devices.

On one device with API level 23 onTokenRefresh method was called.

On another device with API level 19 the onTokenRefresh method was never called.

//MyFirebaseInstanceIdService class

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
```

//manifest

```
<application>
...
     <service android:name=".Services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
```

//build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
```

//build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

Reinstalling app did not help solve this problem.

Comment: How do you know it need to be called on that device?

Comment: OnTokenRefresh is called after installing app on device. I do not know what do you mean by your question.

Comment: You didn't say how you knew it should be getting called, you just said it didn't get called

Answer (score 1):

I just gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49822913/4625829) to a similar question.

Expecting `onTokenRefresh()` to be called on the first install is not the usual case. From my linked answer:

> The `onTokenRefresh()` method doesn't necessarily get called every time the app starts or if it is newly installed. It only triggers on some scenarios (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129054/4625829)).
>
> ...
>
> The `getToken()` method can immediately return the current token **or** null. If its null, it means that the FCM server is not yet finished generating or sending the token back to the client, in which case `onTokenRefresh()` would trigger upon completion.