# Token generation not working call after migrating from GCM to FCM android project

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have converted a project from GCM to FCM but **onTokenRefresh()** function not call.

I have followed this link :
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

**I have completed follow step**

1. Add Firebase project and add application with SHA1 key
2. Remove all code of GCM from my android project
3. Add FCM code

**FCM Code:**

**In manifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".Commonclass.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".Commonclass.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Create two java file
**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token start");
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        GlobalClass.strDeviceToken = refreshedToken;
        Log.e("token",GlobalClass.strDeviceToken);
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token end");
        storeToken(refreshedToken);
    }


    private void storeToken(String token) {
        //saving the token on shared preferences

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(GlobalClass.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(GlobalClass.prefFCMToen, token);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        //Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        try {
            Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(params);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
   }
}
```

I follow this google guidelines 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId
every time I reinstall application but not call **onTokenRefresh()**.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani please help to solve this.

Comment: From your code it seems you have dome something wrong at Firebase console please verify your steps

Comment: Did you added **google.json** file inside app module ?

Comment: @JayRathodRJ yes, added

Comment: @HardikKanak Any logcat errors ? or any log hint ?

Comment: @JayRathodRJ  no any locate an error

Comment: @AndroidTeam add app using package name and SHA1 key, nothing else

Comment: Can you share your manifest file? or re check services are not misplaced

Comment: @AndroidTeam FirebaseMessagingService and FirebaseInstanceIDService add in between <application> tag and my all code work in my demo project perfectly

Answer (score 0):

The `onTokenRefresh()` method doesn't necessarily get called every time the app starts or if it is newly installed. It only triggers on some scenarios (see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45129054/4625829)).

The implementation looks correct. In order to get the current token, you must first call `getToken()` somewhere similar to a MainActivity.

The `getToken()` method can immediately return the current token **or** null. If its null, it means that the FCM server is not yet finished generating or sending the token back to the client, in which case `onTokenRefresh()` would trigger upon completion.

Comment: I have got token null from FCM

Comment: Then it should call `onTokenRefresh()` shortly after. If it doesn't then this is already an unexpected behavior and could be further investigated by Firebase Support. Make sure to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am using react-native-firebase. I am get token on getToken() but still onTokenRefresh() is being triggered. However, it is only happening once in the start. Do you have any idea why?